# How to get out of while loop at the end of String in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a String which is mentioned below i am extracting a 2D array from this string (which i am doing successfully) The problem is that I dont know how to exit the while loop.

```
00000000,00000000,10100111,10100101,11111101,11111111,00000111,00000000,
00000000,00000000,11100010,00100010,11111111,11111111,00000000,10000000,
00000000,00000000,00001001,00001000,00111111,00111111,00000000,00000000,
00100000,00100000,10101110,10100010,10111110,10111110,00000000,00001000,
00000000,00111000,00100011,01111110,01111111,01000011,01000000,01111000,
00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,
00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,
```

I tried to put "x" at the end of string  and ran my while loop like this and it works but Its not feasible for me beacuase I have to read this string from like hundreds of files.

```
while (Data_string[counter] !=  'x' )
{
    while (Data_string[counter] != ',')
    {
        if (Data_string[counter] != '\n')
            SubString += Data_string[counter];

        counter++;
    }
    // here I use Substring to covert to int and then set Substring to empty string
}
```

So I am looking for an efficient solution so i dont have to alter the string,

Thanks..

Comment: If you are accessing the index (Data_string[counter]) you should likely be using a for(each) loop

Comment: sorry my bad i should have been more precise wait i'll edit my question... actually there is another while loop inside which looks for ','

Comment: Can you show us the real code?

Comment: why are you creating 2D array, is it ok to iterate over each element of string

Comment: I think you don't need to do this at all, give a look to my answer.

Comment: @MuhammadSufyanRaza you can also nest for-loops. However you could probably simplify your code with using `Split(',')`, so you don't need the inner while loop anymore.

Comment: @MuhammadSufyanRaza, kindly look into my solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
while (counter < Data_string.Length)
{

}
```

Comment: its perfect!! Thank you!

Comment: @MuhammadSufyanRaza please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would approach:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "00000000,00000000,10100111,10100101,11111101,11111111,00000111,00000000, 00000000,00000000,11100010,00100010,11111111,11111111,00000000,10000000, 00000000,00000000,00001001,00001000,00111111,00111111,00000000,00000000, 00100000,00100000,10101110,10100010,10111110,10111110,00000000,00001000, 00000000,00111000,00100011,01111110,01111111,01000011,01000000,01111000, 00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000, 00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,";

        string[] codes = str.Split(',');
    }
}
```

You don't need a  while loop at all.

If you want to handle cases of blank data there are some approaches:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "00000000,00000000,10100111,10100101,11111101,11111111,00000111,00000000, 00000000,00000000,11100010,00100010,11111111,11111111,00000000,10000000, 00000000,00000000,00001001,00001000,00111111,00111111,00000000,00000000, 00100000,00100000,10101110,10100010,10111110,10111110,00000000,00001000, 00000000,00111000,00100011,01111110,01111111,01000011,01000000,01111000, 00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000, 00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,";

        string[] codes = str.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }
}
```

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "00000000,00000000,10100111,10100101,11111101,11111111,00000111,00000000, 00000000,00000000,11100010,00100010,11111111,11111111,00000000,10000000, 00000000,00000000,00001001,00001000,00111111,00111111,00000000,00000000, 00100000,00100000,10101110,10100010,10111110,10111110,00000000,00001000, 00000000,00111000,00100011,01111110,01111111,01000011,01000000,01111000, 00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000, 00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,";

        string[] codes = str.Split(',').Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) == false).ToArray();            
    }
}
```

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "00000000,00000000,10100111,10100101,11111101,11111111,00000111,00000000, 00000000,00000000,11100010,00100010,11111111,11111111,00000000,10000000, 00000000,00000000,00001001,00001000,00111111,00111111,00000000,00000000, 00100000,00100000,10101110,10100010,10111110,10111110,00000000,00001000, 00000000,00111000,00100011,01111110,01111111,01000011,01000000,01111000, 00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000, 00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,";

        List<string> codes = str.Split(',').ToList();

        codes.RemoveAll(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
    }
}
```

Comment: If `str` ends with a comma, then the last entry in your `codes` will be blank. You'll need to handle that case. I would suggest `string[] codes = str.TrimEnd(',').Split(',');`

Comment: @SNag added blank results handling ^^

Comment: Kindly look into OP's updated question and also my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you just want iterate over each binary record, then no need to convert your string into 2D array and adding `X` at the end of string.

You can easily split array by `,` and iterate over each element of array, something like

```
string input ="00000000,00000000,10100111,10100101,11111101,11111111,00000111,00000000, 00000000,00000000,11100010,00100010,11111111,11111111,00000000,10000000, 00000000,00000000,00001001,00001000,00111111,00111111,00000000,00000000, 00100000,00100000,10101110,10100010,10111110,10111110,00000000,00001000, 00000000,00111000,00100011,01111110,01111111,01000011,01000000,01111000, 00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000, 00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000";

string inputArr = input.TrimEnd(',').split(',');
foreach(string item in inputArr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

From your updated code, it seems like you want to remove all `,` and join all array elements to single string i.e. `SubString`. If you are trying to do this, then you can achieve it in single line

```
string SubString = String.Join("",input.Split(','));
```

No need to use `while/for loop` and/or if loop, this is clear and more readable approach.

POC: [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S9OXD8)

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I was not aware of that.. Actually if you see my answer it is descriptive than yours

Comment: You should do `input.TrimEnd(',').Split(',')` to handle the last comma.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a condition to the loop:

```
while (counter < Data_string.Length && Data_string[counter] !=  'x' )
{
       //some code
}
```

Of course, you could use a `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Data_string.Length && Data_string[i] != x; i++)
{
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have ever tried `foreach`? It will dynamically loop your collection based on its size as long as it is inheritting the `IEnumerable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.Length`:

```
while (counter < Data_string.Length)
    { } // some code
```

---

Side note: Common code style in C# avoids snake_case. Use UpperCamelCase for properties and lowerCamelCase for local or private variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file length as your stopping condition